# Why "rails new" command creates my rails app folders which always read only folders on ubuntu (12.04)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, readonly

I create a new ruby on rails project via typing "rails new project_name" command on terminal. 
The project folders permissions values always read-only (and a key icon on folders and files)
So I have to type "sudo chmod 777 folder_name -R" command on terminal when I create a new rails project.
Why happens this and what should I do ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why would you want to have 777 on all dirs in rails project? This is never a good idea.

Comment: for example I have to edit a migration file via Gedit bu I can't save because of permissions. So I do 777 on all dirs. What should I do ?

Comment: You create a project with the same user you edit it, right? What are the "default" permissions? And what are permissions for dir one level up?

Comment: Yes I create a project with the same user I edit it.

Comment: An the permissions of `stat ../`? (given you're in project dir)